# How to property uninstall Python 3.7?

Tags: python, macos

I'm trying to build a package but would like to uninstall Python 3.7 from my machine first. The build appears to think `/usr/local/opt/python/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/Python` exists on my machine, but it doesn't. I wonder if some process is still linked to `3.7` even when it doesn't exist. Anyone know how to property unlink/uninstall Python 3.7?

Comment: How did you install python 3.7?

Comment: @Mark I'm afraid I don't remember... Possibly by brew, but I've already uninstalled Python with brew.

Comment: WHat is the build system?

Comment: @Mark You mean my `cmake` version? It's 3.15.2.

Answer (score 1):

I had to do this; I used:

```
sudo find / -name '*3.7*' 2>/dev/null | grep -e '[Pp]y' | xargs sudo ls -lad
```

I pipe `stderr` to `/dev/null` to eliminate internal files that even with `sudo` I can't access. Things like:

```
find: /private/var/folders/zz/zyxvpxvq6csfxvn_n00000sm00006d/0: Operation not permitted
```

That returned all the possible Python 3.7 files / folders / symlinks on the machine. Armed with that, I can remove those files.

Pity that `brew` may have left something around. That does happen - I just spent 40 minutes getting VirtualBox manually deinstalled / reinstalled up to 6.01 because something in the uninstall file prevented `brew` from cleaning the existing installation up.

Comment: ewport those errors to Hombrew so they get fixed